# Notice: Undefined property

Tags: php

на странице [php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)
есть код.

```
function &get_instance_ref() {
    static $obj;

    echo 'Статический объект: ';
    var_dump($obj);
    if (!isset($obj)) {
        // Присвоить ссылку статической переменной
        $obj = &new stdclass;
    }
    $obj->property++;
    return $obj;
}
$obj1 = get_instance_ref();
$still_obj1 = get_instance_ref();
```

меня  код абсолютно устраивает, кроме:!
 Когда я добавляю проверку на ошибки.

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
```

он выдает ошибку.
Не могу решить ошибку.
У меня маленький проект и я решил отказаться от oop.
Но не готов отказаться от singleton. Спасибо.

Comment: Наверное, надо define a property, перед тем, как к нему обращаться?

Comment: ооп везде нужно

Comment: Это не ошибка а сообщение от пхп, от том что не задана проперть.

Comment: OOP неплохо, но там черт голову сломает. Без понимания структуры шаблонов проектирования делать нечего. Да и время неделя другая, мне надо сдать работу заказчику с начальными знаниями php. Мне в процедурном проще объяснить если что, что да как работает. но вопрос даже не в этом. Меня самого заинтересовала идея - возможно ли адаптировать этот код в процедурном. я уже вариантов 30 попробовал и все время ошибка. Я не понимаю как мне property определить или инициализировать или найти ей замену?

Answer (score 0):

Ладно. Как всегда все просто. Просто очень долго. Оставляю тем кому интересно решение.

```
function get_instance_ref() {
    static $obj;
    // echo 'Статический объект: ';
    // var_dump( $obj );
    if ( !isset( $obj ) ) {
        $obj = new stdclass();
            $obj->property = null;
    }
    $obj->property++;
    return $obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ИЛИ так.

```
    <?php
function getInstance() {
    $db = [
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8',
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',
    ];
    $option = [ 
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
    ];
    static $obj;
    if ( !isset( $obj ) ) {
        $obj = new PDO( $db[ 'dsn' ], $db[ 'user' ], $db[ 'pass' ], $option );
        $obj->property = null;
    }
    $obj->property++;
    return $obj;
}

$pdo = getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$res = $pdo->query( $sql );
$findAll = $res->fetchAll();

debug( $findAll );
?>
```